# What is the relationship between Paul Atreides and the Guild Navigators?

Tags: dune

So, a Guild Navigator shows up at the Emperor's house at the start of the movie and tells him to kill Paul Atreides.

Paul becomes the god Muad'dib at the end of the movie and vanquishes the Emperor, but the Guild Navigators are still the ones in charge of folding space, aren't they?

What is their relationship with Muad'dib at the point we get to at the end of the movie? I'd have thought that if the Guild Navigators still want Paul dead, they have many ways to make his life difficult.

I'm guessing this is dealt with in the books (assuming the movie is more or less canon with the books).

Comment: "assuming the movie is more or less canon" .... I can tell from that you have never read any of the books.  I strongly recommend reading the first one at least .... and you will see the movie deviated from 'canon' quite a bit.

Comment: The SciFi channel's production was much more faithful to the book, but without the lush verité styling of the Lynch production, initially developed by Jodorowsky and H.R. Giger.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The Guild Navigators are **terrified** of Paul. He possesses the ability to destroy the only supply of Spice in the known galaxy and due to their dependence on it, they're utterly unwilling to go against him.

> "The power to destroy a thing is the absolute control  over it. You've
>   agreed I have that power. We are not here to discuss or to  negotiate
>   or to compromise. **You will obey my orders or suffer the immediate 
>   consequences!**"

In the subsequent books, his total dominance of the Spacing Guild leads him to one military victory after another since his troops now have total freedom of movement in space (at zero cost) whereas his enemies are now confined to their own planets unless they can come up with monumentally expensive spice bribes.

To quote from the book:

> "Stop playing the fool," Paul barked [at the Emperor]. "The Guild is like a village
>   beside a  river. They need the water, but can only dip out what they
>   require. They cannot  dam the river and control it, because that
>   focuses attention on what they take, it brings down eventual
>   destruction. The spice flow, that's their river, and I have built a
>   dam. But my dam is such that you cannot destroy it without  destroying
>   the river."

Comment: Good summation.  In history this is called a Hydraulic Empire.

Comment: @PatrickHughes - Indeed, albeit subsequent books in the Dune Series showed that there were non-spice alternatives to both space travel and bene-gesserit mental powers...

Comment: @Richard that's a bit of a spoiler

Comment: @dreamwalker - Vader is Luke's father.

Comment: I find Frank Herbert comes up with awesome stuff, with a caveat. "only source of spice" seems to ignore chemical engineering. Same way The White Plague seemed to ignore cloning.

Comment: @almo - Reverse-engineering is discussed. Apparently the spice is not easy to replicate. It takes the Tleilaxu thousands of years to manage it.

Comment: If it is a physical compound, then I find that defies suspension of disbelief. The Dune universe doesn't have magic, so despite it being discussed, I find that he just needed to ignore chemical engineering on this one. It's fine within the story, and is necessary for it to work. But it doesn't make sense, in my opinion.

Comment: @almo - There are no computers in the Dune universe. Those would be essential to replicate a substance chemically. Also, there are many things we can't reconstitute (fine wine for example) despite having a complete understanding of their chemical structure.

Comment: Ok on the computers, but I wouldn't use our inability to reconstitute something to defend theirs. :)

Comment: @Richard - NOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOOO!

Comment: @DVK - Speaking of which, the cat was out of the bag before the film even hit cinemas courtesy of David Prowse' big mouth; https://static.squarespace.com/static/51b3dc8ee4b051b96ceb10de/51ce6099e4b0d911b4489b79/51ce61cde4b0d911b44a19a0/1289268304837/1000w/Star-Wars-Article1.jpeg

Comment: @Almo Melange is incredibly hard to synthesize. We see this in many real-world situations today, like spider silk, blood and antivenom. Other natural substances that we do synthesize often have unintended effects. E.G. synthetic marijuana has often been cited legally as a narcotic causing violent behavior and disassociation, neither of which is considered even rarely to result from the use of natural marijuana. What we know, after the Tleilaxu make a suitable artificial substitute, is that in addition to very narrow conditions, spice needs to develop inside LIFE.

Comment: Reverend Mothers can move individual atoms around in molecules in their bodies to survive the Water of Life. Why not synthesize spice? If it's a chemical, they should be able to do this. I don't buy any of these arguments. BUT I still don't really care. Great books.

Comment: @Almo Assuming there's no *technical* bar to a Reverend Mother transmuting whatever substance into spice, the reason might be logistical. That is an individual RM could be limited to a prohibitively small amount of melange produced per unit of initial substance per unit of time. Since we know how the Tleilaxu eventually synthesize the spice, your argument that RMs *should* be able to do it is very likely correct. Assuming FH didn't just leave this discrepancy dangling, we should be able to suss out some rationale for the BG forebearing production.

Comment: @TravisSmithofBexar - Since the BG need to ingest spice at a fairly consistent rate, presumably the rate of production is lower than the rate of consumption. This would allow them to eke out a supply, but not replace it.

Comment: @Richard Nicely squaring what we know about the value of spice **and** the BG behavior of not producing it.